# "An unidentified program wants to access your computer" in vista

Tags: uac

How to obtain code sign certificate and how to sign the program with it?

Any amount will pay for it? or without paying dollars how to get signing?

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are looking for [something like this](http://www.verisign.com/code-signing/information-center/code-signing-microsoft-developers/index.html).